# Comparing 2d Arrays which are continually repopulated

Tags: java, android, arrays, math, multidimensional-array

I'm creating a motion detection application for Android. Although I'm having issues with my detection algorithm:

```
public boolean compareBitmaps()
{

    /*I'm creating 2 x 2D arrays which will continually be repopulated 
    every 2 frames with the pixel data of that frame based on even or odd
    (frames are collected in an ArrayList 'BIT') 
    BIT(0) will be stored in compare1
    BIT(1) will be stored in compare2
    BIT(2) will be stored in compare1 and so on...*/

    int [][] compare1 = new int[width][height];
    int [][] compare2 = new int[width][height];
    int bmpCount = BIT.size();

    boolean noMotion = true;

    //This is where I determine wheter even or odd using the modulus %
    for (int x=0; x<bmpCount; x++)
        if(x%2!=0)
        {

                System.out.println("Odd");
                getPixels1(compare1, x);

        }
        else
        {

                System.out.println("Even");
                getPixels2(compare2, x);

        }

        //Here I'm looking to continually compare the returned pixel colours
        // of the 2D arrays
        if(!Arrays.deepEquals(compare1, compare2))
        {
            System.out.println("No Motion");
            return noMotion = false;

        }
        else
        {
        return noMotion = true;
        }
}

private void getPixels1(int[][] compare1, int x) 
{
    for(int i = 0; i<width; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<height; j++)
        {

            compare1[j][i] = BIT.get(x).getPixel(j, i);

        }
    }
}

private void getPixels2(int[][] compare2, int x) 
{
    for(int i = 0; i<width; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<height; j++)
        {
            compare2[j][i] = BIT.get(x).getPixel(j, i);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using `println()` to help me debug, - Currently the console prints "Odd" which (correct me if I'm wrong) is wrong for element(0)? And when I next step over the application breaks.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong, any help would be appreciated

Many Thanks,

Comment: As you are implementing motion detection type app and comparing each even and odd frame, from my little knowledge i think it is too fast and consumes lots of CPU power, my suggestion is to compare the frames at low rate some thing like after 15 frames.

Comment: Sorry what do you mean compare after 15 frames? Like compare frame 0 with frame 14 and 15 with 29 and so on?

Comment: Just a friendly reminder. I noticed you haven't accepted an answer to any of your questions. Did you know that you can accept answers to show that it solved your problem? Just click the checkbox right next to the voting arrow. This lets the community know that you're actively engaged in your questions.

Answer (score 3):

Your logic is reversed.

If `x % 2` returns `0` that means `x` is divisible by two with no remainder, i.e. *even*.

```
4 % 2 = 0 // even
5 % 2 = 1 // odd
```

Comment: Thanks I didn't notice that small ! mistake, I've swapped the print statements as advised but the application is still going to break regardless

Comment: Hmm... I have no idea what `getPixel1()` and `getPixel2()` do, but if it is critical that "BIT(0) will be stored in compare1" then your sorting is still reversed `x=0` is in `compare2`, `x=1` is in `compare1`, etc...

Comment: I've added the other methods in. Simply the nested for loops go through x & y and collect the pixel colours for each pixel. It is not essential that they are stored in that order just as long as the odd & even ones are separate

Comment: I have never compared images pixel by pixel, so I cannot suggest a good alternative. But I can see that each time you call either `getPixel_()` method you write over every value in that array from `[0][0]` to `[width][height]`. You need to rework the logic so that you only fetch and store one pixel...